# How do I disable Linux media polling?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, udev

I have a USB floppy drive (for reasons, don't ask). When it's plugged into a modern PC with Debian and udev, something is pinging the drive every couple of seconds --- I believe it's looking to see if there's a disk in the drive.

This is causing the drive to make an audible clunking noise and it's really annoying.

`blktrace` has confirmed that something's sending commands down the wire:

```
  8,64   7        3     2.047998323  2930  I   N 0 [kworker/7:0]
  8,64   7        4     2.048002857  2930  D   N 0 [kworker/7:0]
  8,64   5        2     2.094203959    36  C   N [65531]
  8,64   7        5     4.095999615  2930  I   N 0 [kworker/7:0]
  8,64   7        6     4.096004486  2930  D   N 0 [kworker/7:0]
  8,64   5        3     4.142187593    36  C   N [65531]
```

(etc)

Unfortunately process 2930 is a generic kworker and process 36 is ksoftirqd, so all I can tell is that it's coming from the kernel somewhere.

Searching the interwebs has revealed that udev used to do media polling like this, but since about 2014 it's been replaced with in-kernel media polling instead. More searching has revealed that this can be disabled with the `hal-disable-polling` command. Yet more searching shows that these commands have been removed from Debian. I haven't yet figured out what they've been replaced with.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which Debian version in general? Do you have any version of _udisks_ running? Are any processes holding the drive's /dev node open?

Comment: Debian testing amd64, udisksd is running, no processes holding the dev node open.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop it for that device with:

```
# udisks --inhibit-polling /dev/your_device
```

or for all devices with:

```
# udisks --inhibit-all-polling
```

Comment: That only exists in `udisks`, and Debian has `udisks2`, which doesn't have that command. There's a `udisksctl` command but that seems to do something entirely different.

Comment: @DavidGiven you are right but I have both udisks and udisks2 in my Debian 10, that's why I suggested it. Not sure if it is installable though, maybe from [sid or jessie](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=udisks).

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial workaround to this problem:

The solution has been tested under Ubuntu 14.04 and should work also on more recent versions of Ubuntu or Debian.

This solution works only for the cheap Teac USB floppy controllers (for other usb controllers you will maybe have to adapt the solution yourself):

In the terminal simply type

```
lsscsi
```

(if it's not installed type sudo apt-get install lsscsi):

```
Output: [6:0:0:0]    disk    TEAC     USB UF000x       0.00
```

If you don't see TEAC and USB UF000x when the floppy drive is connected, this solution is not for you.

Create this file with administrative privileges : `/etc/udev/rules.d/00-teacfloppy.rules`

Paste in this line:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0644", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}="-1"
```

Save and reboot.

The drive will seek for a few seconds then the motor will quickly stop.

Comment: I had the same problem in Arch and Kali. The answer worked for me, except I had to change the `events_poll_msecs attribute` to `0` to stop the constant polling: `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0644", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", ATTR{events_poll_msecs}="0"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to configure the in-kernel polling interval is through the `/sys` sysfs filesystem.

Easiest way to find the path is:

```
find /sys -name events_poll_msecs
```

After that the interval can be changed with:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/..../block/sr0/events_poll_msecs
```

Value 0 disables polling and -1 uses the default from `/sys/module/block/parameters/events_dfl_poll_msecs`.